# unable to select multiple rows on ultrawingrid when stylefile loaded

Tags: c#, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid, wingrid

I have a system with many forms, so I applied a theme file ("theme.isl") on load of the system and there for its applied on all infragistics items, but on a specific form I need to multiple select rows, I tried setting 
myGrid.override.selectTypeRow=extended, also inside of the band but doesn't work, then deactivate the style myGrid.useAppStyle=false, and then its works, can someone come to this problem, any solution

Answer (score 0):

ok fellas, feel really silly, apparently its selects multiple rows, but my appearance file has no style for selectedrows, so if anyone gets to this, just put a style to selectedrows on your file and it will show you the selectedrows that are being selected